# SCSS variables using

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-cli

I'm currently working on a Angular 4 app with the angular-cli and I came across a small problem. I'm trying to create a component that can load styling dynamically.

I have a component `ComponentX` which should use a SCSS variable `color` for example. However the value of `color` should depend on the different SCSS I'm loading through the angular-cli defined app's.

I'm trying to find a good solution however I can't make this work. I tried using a simple import, but with no success.

I hope you can send me in the right direction :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put _variables.scss in your `src/` folder and add these lines to `.angular-cli.json`

```
"stylePreprocessorOptions": {
  "includePaths": [
    "."
  ]
}
```

then use `@import 'variables';` in your component.scss files.

It won't get easier than this, because by design every component.scss file is compiled in its own scope to keep components separated.

Comment: Thanks, this is what i was looking for. I found this link later that contains some info about stylePreprocessorOptions:
https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-global-styles